# Using ArcMap API to find coordinates of points in shapefile?

Tags: arcgis-10.2, arcobjects, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I need to find some reference or even C#.Net example code of how to use the ArcMap 10.2 programmers API.  I have got a CSV file with X, Y and elevation coordinates of soil samples and I want to write an extension to import the point data and save it as a shapefile in a project.

I have been through the current API documentation and I am a bit lost.

Comment: I'd agree that the documentation is lacking for some things...Is this more of a learning exercise or actually what you are trying to accomplish? You could easily do this with the existing geoprocessing tools within ArcGIS, using either model builder or Python.

Comment: It's both - I have to build the actual extension to fit into my existing C# based tools and I want to learn how to do it to get a better understanding of the API for future refs.  I have quite a few tools that i want to convert to full ArcMAP extensions.

Answer (score 2):

I'd start with the concepts documentation at http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/conceptualhelp/ before diving into the API docs.  There are lots of samples in the concepts documents.

However for your task, I would recommend that you consider using the GeoProcessing tools and either Python or ModelBuilder to script the task, for the following reasons:

1. The GP tools are much more *coarse grained*, and you can accomplish the example task in just a few lines. (The same task would be several orders of magnitude more code in ArcObjects to accomplish the same thing).
2. Unless you are an old timer COM programmer, ArcObjects is much more difficult to program with, even using the .Net bindings, than using ModelBuilder or Python.
3. The next generation ArcGIS Pro will not support ArcObjects as we know it, so you would be investing in learning an obsolete technology.

Answer (score 0):

Using Python and [arcpy](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//000v000000v7000000) library is probably the way I'd choose for your task. You might also want to take a look at [writing geometries](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//002z0000001v000000).